# leashed dog on community college campus

Tags: united-states, virginia, pets, state-university, dog

I live in Virginia. I am told that I am not allowed to walk my leashed dog anywhere 'on campus' of our local community college which, they say, includes the parking lots.

Their website only addresses the issue by saying only service animals are allowed on campus. Is that enough legal 'juice' to automatically exclude walking a leashed dog in the parking lot?

Answer (score 3):

A property owner has the legal right to set the rules for their property, which can include a no-pets policy. This includes property owned by the government, by government agencies, and government-funded operations. The service animal exception is the accommodation for disability that is required under the ADA and analogous state laws. So if you take your dog for a walk through the parking lot, they can tell you to pack it up and go away.